# C# sequence number issue in database

Tags: c#, sql, datetime

I have a column in the database table i.e. transaction Id. Its data type is var char(50). Now I want to save a row by combining the current date with a sequential number generated.

For Example `10/9/2016` is the date so first transaction is saved like 10920161 and the next one like `10920162` and so on. The sequential number is reset to 1 after every day.

How can I do this?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server, it can be as simple as:

```
transactionId =  
CONCAT(DATEPART(MONTH, GETDATE()), 
       DATEPART(DAY, GETDATE()), 
       DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE()),
       (SELECT COUNT(1) 
        FROM tableName 
        WHERE CONVERT(DATE, dateColumn) = CONVERT(DATE, getdate())) + 1)
```

Get the Number of transactions for that date, and add one to it. Concat that with a formatted string of Today's Date.

If you already have 3 records for today's date, the result would be:

```
100920164
```

Running [SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8e4b4/1)

Edit: EF suggested snippet:

```
string dateStr = DateTime.Today.ToString("Mdyyyy");
DateTime todayMidnight = DateTime.Today;
DateTime tomorrowMidnight = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1);

obj.transactionId = dateStr + 
                      context.tableName.Count(x=> x.dateColumn >= todayMidnight 
                      && x.dateColumn < tomorrowMidnight) + 1;
```

Comment: But i have added datetime of the transaction as a whole for each transaction. That is not only date but the time too.

Comment: @AzherAleem `CONVERT(DATE, dateColumn)` extracts the date part out of a DateTime column. Check the SQL fiddle, it has a `DateTime` column.

Comment: @AzherAleem Just convert the above query to linq !

Comment: @AzherAleem Check the edit, this is a snippet that shows the idea, play around it to fit your needs. If you're not familiar with Entity framework, roll a tutorial as this is outside the scope of this question !

Comment: i just ran it and made to transactions.

Comment: 1. 201610901
2. 201610911
This is the result i got in db. the second one should be 201610902

Comment: @AzherAleem You can't run this on existing data, this is a solution to be triggered for-each insert ! It is common sense, just think about it ! Understanding the solution is more important that running a working solution provided by someone else !

Comment: To run on existing data, you need to get all data, group them by date and run a for loop with a counter to set each transaction to the date + counter ! Alternatively, you can run a raw SQL Query that partitions data by date and append the initial query posted here to it. All these are different question that are not stated in your original question.

Comment: How can i do that? :(

Comment: Done :D Rate my question too :) Thank you so much :)